# Cannot modified data frame to desired structure using if-else statements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have a data set like this

```
data = {'Name': ['Ron','Charlie','Harry','Hermione','Luna','Hagrid','Draco']}
kdf = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

After this I add a column to my data frame as

```
kdf['x'] = 0
```

Now I want to fill the column x with 1's in specific places according to the list below

```
ls = [True, True , False, True, False, False, False]
```

For example I want 1's to be in Ron,Charlie and Hermione's row for that I wrote the below code

```
for i in ls:
    if i:
        kdf['x'] = 1
        print(i)
    else:
        kdf['x'] = 0
```

But the data set after this modification had 0's in all rows of column x, if I change 0 to 2 in else statement all rows in column x has 2, if I remove else statement complete all rows of column x have 1's in them

I don't understand why is this happening I also added print(i) in if statement to see if all of them are somehow understood as True but print(i) returns 3 True's so that seems okay.

I was expecting to my data frame to be modified such that could x has 1's in 1st, 2nd and 4th row but I am getting 1's in all rows of column x;if I change 0 to 2 in else statement all rows in column x has 2, if I remove else statement complete all rows of column x have 1's in them;I also added print(i) in if statement to see if all of them are somehow understood as True but print(i) returns 3 True's so that seems okay.

Edit: Someone suggested me this link [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column) and this is great I appreciate it but I want to understand what is the problem with my code not working in desired way.

Comment: `kdf['x'] = np.where(ls, 1, 0)`

Comment: I am voting against reopening your question, however the question in your edit is legitimate. When you do `kdf['x'] = N` you set the whole column to `N`, I recommend you go through the [Indexing and Selecting Data section of the pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)